# Foreach/for loop with List<T> won't update properly

Tags: c#, list, loops, xna

I'm having some issues with a `foreach` loop and `List<T>`

```
foreach (DefenceTerminal defence in DefenceManager.defenceCollection)
{
    defence.ReadNetworkPacket(packetReader);
    //this is a very simple function that just sets defence.damage = to whatever
    //it properly sends the value and sets it
    //defence.damage is a int
}
```

when I leave the loop, the value... disappears. (It fails to change)

all values remain unchanged once the loop is left

the list is accessed in the update in a similar fashion.

I have used `for` loops as an alternative as well, so i guess it is more of a `List<T>` issue more then anything else.

I would prefer to keep using a list, however. Suggestions?

And here is the very simple function for those who want very simple functions

```
    public void ReadNetworkPacket(PacketReader packetReader)
    {
        damage = packetReader.ReadInt32();
    }
```

IT works, the list and loop doesn't.

Again: While within the loop Everything works fine, i have checked multiple times, but it doesn't... stick... like it makes its own little personal list to mess with then drops it after its done, which is unhelpful when your trying to update the list. Its a strange idiosyncrasy having to do with List I'm sure.

Other crap:

```
public static List<DefenceTerminal> defenceCollection = new List<DefenceTerminal>();

        for (int i = 0; i < factionCount; i++)
        {
            DefenceTerminal d = new DefenceTerminal();
            for (int j = 0; j < defenceLimit; j++)
            {
                defenceCollection.Add(d);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the value disappears_?

Comment: It fails to change once leaving the loop, it remains as it was, any access reveals it to be unchanged in value.

Comment: Can you clarify which value disappears?  Is it `defence.damage`?

Comment: Hard to do more than guess without seeing code for DefenceManager.defenceCollection (how it's created and whether it's a field, or property), and DefenceTerminal.ReadnetworkPacket.

Comment: Please show source code of ReadNetworkPacket()

Comment: Is `damage` just a non-static field in the `DefenceTerminal` class?

Answer (score 1):

Please post more code, but I feel that you have created your collection too local, move it higher in the class scope, like a private member variable to the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `DefenceTerminal` is a `struct` and therefore a `value` type.  This means that as you go through the `foreach loop` you are just changing a copy.  Try using a classic `for loop` and index the actual list instead.

Comment: It is a class, and as I said, for loops result in the same issue.